# Objective C: UIScrollView inside a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

Is it possible to put another scrollview inside a scrollview??

because in one page of my scrollview i need to put scrollable images.

I already tried it but it's not scrolling.

Can it be done? or is there another way??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sure.

I suggest you to see [PhotoScroller sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html) in Apple doc.

Hope it helps.

**Edit**

If you provide some code, maybe it is possible to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a scroll view inside another scroll view. But image scrolling is possible with a single scroll view itself. You must have missed to set the delegate or set contentSize. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a scrollView on a scrollView, it doesn't matter.

the scrollView is not scrolling, did you call setContentSize?